# Strange tkinter button behaviour?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Okay so I had a problem that I managed to fix but I don't understand why what I did worked and wondered if anyone could explain it to me? I made a class to create buttons in tkinter, this is the code I used:
    class Buttons:

```
#Takes input for location values of button and assigns them to variable
def __init__(self, letter, column, row):
    self.letter = letter
    self.column = column
    self.row = row

#Function to create and display each button using arguments given
def create(self):
    self.tkbutton = tk.Button(window, text=self.letter, height = 1, width = 1, bg = colour, font=FONT,
                     command=lambda : check(self.letter))
    self.tkbutton.place(relx=self.column, rely=self.row)
```

The strange behavior I got was when I tried to set the sizes. I used 
   widget.winfo_height() 
to get the height and then similar for the width of the biggest button so I could use it for all the buttons. I then set the height and width in the standard button construction to these values but when I did they came out massive, all different size and going off the edge of the screen. Inputting the height and width values as 1 seems to have made them all the same size so could anyone explain why this is?

Python 3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`winfo_height` returns values in pixels. The `height` option for buttons and labels treats the values as a number of average-sized characters, unless the button or label only contains an image.

Instead of using `place`, you can use `grid` with appropriate options to make sure that every widget is exactly the same size. `place` is rarely the right choice when laying out a GUI. Tkinter is very good at computing sizes and positions.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect